# What is the common meaning and usage of "get mad"?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english, british-english

I've always understood "to get mad" to mean "to get (very) angry".

Checking the expression in online dictionaries, I've found the following definitions:

***[Don't get mad, get even](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/don-t-get-mad-get-even),*** in Cambridge Dictionary, meaning: 
​

> - something that you say in order to tell someone not to be angry when another person has upset them, but instead to do something that will upset that person very much.
>
>   - *This is my advice to wives whose husbands have left them for a younger woman - don't get mad, get even!*

while the McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms says:

***[Get mad (at something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+mad+at+something):***

> - to muster great physical strength and determination in order to do something.
>
>   - *You’re gonna have to get mad at it if you want to move it.*

I could not find other definitions of "get mad" and the two stated above appear to convey different, though related, meanings.

Questions:

Is  "to get angry" the more common meaning  of "get mad" both in BrE and AmE?

Is the connotation suggested in the second example only an AmE one?

Comment: You might want to give it a look: [US usage of 'mad'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17721/us-usage-of-mad).

Comment: "Mad" meaning "insane" is fine in AmE, so you have understand the context to know which is meant.  For example,  "she's mad about that boy" (figuratively) implies "insane", while "don't make me mad" implies "angry".  To "get mad" is to get angry, while to "go mad" is to go insane.

Comment: @Andrew - I am aware of the different meanings and usages  of "mad". My question is specific on "get mad" and the definitions I've found about it. Their meaning and usage both in AmE and BrE.

Comment: The McGraw-Hill definition implies what you first suggested: the reason you have managed to muster that greater physical strength is BECAUSE you have gotten very angry ("mad").

Comment: An absolute beginner is not able to write the kind of sentences you wrote in  your question. Ergo, I doubt you are an "absolute beginner". And you say: I've always understood "to get mad" to mean..[...] So, that use of always and the present perfect also suggests you are not an absolute beginner. Get mad is not used in BrE to mean: get angry. They do say, however, to get cross. And in English, for insanity, it's GO: to go mad. You cannot get mad with the meaning of insanity in BrE or AmE.

Comment: The McGraw-Hill definition seems very strange to me; I've never heard "get mad" used in that way.  The only way to interpret it that makes sense is the way that JamieB mentions.

Comment: There is no get mad in British English. GET mad is AmE. There is be mad or go mad in BrE (become INSANE). In AmE too though we tend to say: go crazy (for insanity) but we can also say: to go mad for insanity.

Comment: If you click on the correct usages in the Cambridge Dictionary, it is exactly as I explained. That idiom: don't get mad, get even is AmE. And shown in a translation from the Chinese with no qualification as to AmE or BrE.

Comment: @Lambie I think the username was meant as an ironic, tongue-in-cheek epithet. It's not meant to be taken literally, as anyone can clearly see, the OP's command of English is definitely superior to that of a beginner! Or maybe the OP is a fan of [David Bowie's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8NZa9wYZ_U) music :)

Comment: @Lambie Please keep comments focused on the question. There are plenty of user names on the SE network that shouldn't be taken too literally. Maybe Absolute Beginner is a beginner at being absolute but a relative expert :)

Comment: And I am not a lamb. :)

Comment: @Lambie - the sense is that we are all beginners  and, among all,  I am the absolute one :)

Answer (score 5):

Anger: in BrE

to get cross; to get angry (among many others but not with get)

Anger: in AmE (among many others but not with get)
to get mad, to get angry, to get cross

**In both varieties of English**:
insanity is:

To go [become] mad but: to be mad in BrE means to be insane.

Whereas in AmE: to be mad means to be angry.

Minor point of slang:

in BrE, to get pissed means to get drunk. In AmE, to get pissed means to be angry.

I sincerely hope you do not get too confused.
As you are most certainly not an absolute beginner, this stuff is right up your alley. :) PS: I am not pissed in either sense, BrE or AmE.

Comment: All the above is very interesting, but it does not really answer my question, which asks  specifically about   ***"get mad"*** meaning and usage in BrE and AmE.

Comment: Yes, it answers it.  You have not read it carefully enough. There is no "get mad" in BrE. Ergo, there is no difference  with AmE for the expression: to get mad meaning angry. Read it again. I went over and beyond what you asked. British people get angry or get cross.

Comment: The expression from the Cambridge Dictionary is a BrE one.

Comment: That is a mistake. The Brits would only say that if influenced by AmE. It simply is not BrE. Period. You are not looking in the right place: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mad That is BrE

Comment: This is American English: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mad

Comment: You have to CLICK on BRITISH or AMERICAN on the page. Then,  you can see the differences I laid out above.

Comment: Mad, BrE: ​
A2 [ after verb ] ***informal very angry or annoyed:***
He's always complaining and it makes me so mad.
mainly us Are you still mad at me?
***uk Kerry got really mad with Richard*** for not doing the washing up.
uk Bill's untidiness drives me mad.

Comment: The entry says: /mainly us/ Are you still mad at me?

Comment: The expression in bold /U.K./ Kerry got really mad...anyway thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Yes, but it is NOT usual in the UK.

Comment: I suppose there are still some people living under rocks in the UK who have never had any influence from American literature, theatre, movies, TV, etc - but the rest of us aren't so dogmatic about what "isn't BrE".

Comment: @alephzero and vice-versa, what with Harry Potter, Dr. Who, and all the other good stuff from British telly.

Comment: @Lambie - I am not sure the Cambridge Dictionary is "wrong" and that "get mad" is not common  in BrE, whatever its origin. My question still remains about its usage, especially the AmE one. Is the Mc-Griw Hill Dictionary wrong or unclear about the expression. Why should they give a "stretched" definition as the main one? Any reference to support what you are saying?

Comment: One has to be very careful about relying only on dictionaries or Ngram when discussing use of spoken language and usual usage. I can google too. But I have been listening to BrE speakers my entire life and they tend NOT to use it as much as AmE speakers use it (which is almost 100% of the time when meaning to become angry). It is NOT THAT common in BrE. And like much of what is happening, AmE is the influence.

Comment: Finally, your two examples mean exactly the same thing. There is no difference. I have emailed the grand expert on these matters: www.worldwidewords.org. Let's see what he has to say about the matter....

Comment: My British friend (university educated, a linguist but sold newspapers for years in the City) just responded to my email:"Well Lambie, In the UK, the USUAL way of saying to "get angry" is either to get angry or to get cross. Get mad is typically American and is not usually the expression of choice in BrE. Though used at times,it is the result of American usage."

Answer (score 3):

"Mad" has a number of meanings, the most common of which are "angry" and "insane".  I think the other definition that you found, "to muster great physical strength", is not a *definition* as much as derivation from something that happens when you get *really* angry.

Even the example sentence implies actual *anger*, like a sports coach telling his players, "Get angry!  Get mean!" He doesn't intend that they should actually dislike the other team, but rather they should *pretend* to be mad so they can muster greater physical effort.

I don't know much about the difference in use between AmE and BrE, but the expression "You're mad!" -- meaning that you are acting or thinking in a way that seems insane -- might be more common in BrE, judging from what I see on television (although modern slang seems to lean more towards, "You're mental!" or even "You're barking!").

Edit:  Apparently to "get mad" is an AmE expression that doesn't exist in BrE (although it's likely they understand what an American means if he says it).

Answer (score 1):

A meaning of *get X* is to become, of one's own accord, or implying that one can/should control X.

*Get mad at * then means to become mad at X, and it implies you can/should control how mad you are.

People are generally more energetic and decisive when they are mad, so if someone is talking colorfully, they may say you have to *get mad* at something, if that something requires a lot of strength or willpower.

So this is a possible figurative or "stretched" meaning of *get mad*, but I don't believe it's really the only or default thing *get mad* means.

> You’re gonna have to get mad at it if you want to move it.

You could substitute *angry* and I think it would still be understood as not literally getting angry about it, but just to gather enough willpower or strength to do it.

Comment: As I said in my question the two definitions are (obviously) related. But the second one appears to be very specific, a common one, not just a "stretched" one given that the dictionary made an entry for it, but it does not mention the 'angry" one.

Comment: Unless people are saying this a lot now I don't understand why the dictionary lists that as a meaning, to be honest.  I don't hear people casually say "get mad" meaning to gather motivation, it's usually only on the occasion when they are trying to be expressive or unique with their language.  Maybe this is a different thing in BrE.

Answer (score 1):

The **catchphrase**, because it should be considered as a whole item and not broken into separate pieces, is:

> don't get mad, get even

The Cambridge English Dictionary describes its (the entire catch phrase) meaning perfectly, and the example it quotes also indicates its origin.

> This is my advice to wives whose husbands have left them for a younger woman — don't get mad, get even!

The same dictionary defines the idiom, **[get even](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-even)**, as

> to punish someone who has done something bad to you by doing something equally bad to that person

The catch phrase is a **borrowing** of a north American expression, one which might be said to a woman whose husband had left her, or, had been unfaithful with a younger woman. The wronged wife would be incited to **employ the energy of her anger in a more productive way**, i.e. to channel that anger in order to wreak revenge.

Instead of losing her temper (‘get mad’ AmEng), she should seek financial compensation (‘get even’) or do anything that would "punish" the unfaithful spouse or partner.

It appears that this catchphrase has been adopted in British English, and can be used in any context where a person advises a wronged person to focus their energy in getting personal justice.

For those who want to learn more: the American etymologist, and OED contributor, Barry Popik, cites 1956 (Newport) as the earliest written instance, but the expression in speech most likely predates that year.

Judging by the following citations, the American English *get mad* has crept into the British vernacular, and whether native speakers like it or not, it is here to stay.

### British English ‘get mad’

Literary examples of *get mad* (i.e. to become angry or extremely upset) found in the British National Corpus ([link](http://phrasesinenglish.org/searchBNC.html)) Tip: Write **get_mad** and click on the search button.

> Maria nodded, staring straight at Clare with her bulging eyes. "He **gets mad** when Gary doesn't sleep, he says it's my fault, he says I make him do it -- and --" She stopped again. "How old's Gary?" asked Clare, after the silence had lasted a little while. 
>   [...]
>   Maria shook her head convulsively. “He was shouting at me. Calling me. I asked him —I told him ‘Shut up or you'll wake Cathy too’ and **he got madder** — he — he thinks — he says I keep them awake so — so — so I don't have to go to bed with him.”

*[Her living image](https://books.google.it/books?id=91OglLdQn9UC&pg=PT57&lpg=PT57&dq=%22gets%20mad%20when%20Gary%20doesn%27t%20sleep%22&source=bl&ots=75s2r-t6BT&sig=0HZfoyT25KMxKsPU4A5mrX-m1P4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy6qaxk8bPAhWCPBQKHTGDA60Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22gets%20mad%20when%20Gary%20doesn't%20sleep%22&f=false)* By Jane Rogers (1984)

> I woke up a few times and got Mum out of bed all bleary-eyed and irritable in her nightie telling her a bogey-man was after me. First she was terrified there was a burglar, then when she'd searched the house from top to bottom she **got mad** and shoved me back to bed. You can picture it, can't you.

*Gate-crashing the Dream Party* By Alison Leonard (1989)

> If my Mam **got mad** with me for something I'd done -- or more often something I hadn't done -- she used to make moaning noises and stagger about the house as if she was dying. My Dad used to say, "Now look what you've done to your mother," and if I answered back, he would start pelting things at me -- plates, cups, his dinner, the carving knife, and once a picture of Jesus floating up to heaven with a lamb tucked under each arm

*An alternative assembly book* Hoy, Mike and Hoy, Linda, Longman Group UK Ltd, Harlow (1991)

> Constipated? **Get mad!** A group of constipated patients who were hypnotised then made to feel angry soon got rid of their problem

Excerpt from *She* magazine, London: The National Magazine Company Ltd (1989)

---

Further [evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20mad%2C%20get%20angry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20mad%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20angry%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cget%20mad%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20angry%3B%2Cc1) from Google Ngram suggests that the trend for *get mad* is increasing, but it still has a long way to go before it catches up with *get angry*.  Although the chances of that ever occurring, in either American or British English, is considerably low because *get mad* is INFORMAL.

[image]

---

The answers supplied by [@Andrew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/105724/1694), [@Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/105730/1694), and [@LawrenceC](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/105725/1694) have already explained the different meanings and usages of “get mad” in AmEng and  BrEng.

Comment: My impression is that "get mad" (meaning get very angry) is used in BrE more that the answers suggest.  The expression is not that uncommon, especially  in writing, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+mad&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20mad%3B%2Cc0, and curiuosly it is not adequately covered by dictionaries.